# How can I use my Active Directory credentials to log in to my Linux machine?

Tags: authentication, active-directory

I would like to use the same username/password to log in to my Linux machine as I do for a Windows machine that authenticates against Active Directory.

In particular, what I want is:

- When I log in via LightDM or SSH, I am authenticated with my AD credentials.
- If my account does not exist locally, an initial one is created.
- I do not want to have to manually synchronise passwords.
- I don't need the option to create non-AD-authenticated accounts on the local machine, but I don't mind if the possibility exists either.

I do not administer the AD or what it runs on. I have full administrative control of the Linux machine. I have installed Samba and can reliably browse network shares using my AD credentials.

I initially tried to follow the [ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto), but it appears that I would need to be an administrator of the AD for those instructions to work (this also applies to some other, very [similar instructions](https://serverfault.com/questions/135396/how-to-authenticate-linux-accounts-against-an-active-directory-and-mount-a-windo) I found elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not administer the AD or what it runs on. I have full
> administrative control of the Linux machine. I have installed Samba
> and can reliably browse network shares using my AD credentials.

You don't need Samba. The "problem" here is you can't "join" the Linux system
to your AD as you don't have permissions on AD for this (to add a computer to
the domain). Moreover you can't use kerberos as you won't be able to generate
keytab for the Linux system.

But you can use LDAP via SSSD. Since your AD user login to the Linux system
would provide his username/password, SSSD-LDAP provider would forward this
credentials to AD LDAP and if succeeded, then you will be allowed to login.
pam_mkhomedir.so would create the user directory locally if needed.

Comment: Hi! Yes, this was what I ended up doing, but I moved on from that workplace ages ago and forgot all about this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not the Micro$oft AD admin, do some MBA (**M**anagement **B**y walking **A**round) and talk to the guy/gal because to do integration between Linux and Windows, you need willing admins *on both sides*.

(Putting bottles of real French Champagne right in front of anyone has helped me in 100% of the cases.)

Comment: This puzzles me, because clearly I don't need AD admin intervention to authenticate to access samba shares. So it's possible for my Linux box to have the AD verify my credentials *somehow*. Why not at login time?

Comment: samba is basically a hack of old Microsoft technology (lanman) whereas AD is a combination of LDAP, DNS and Kerberos! So it's a bit more complex.  I did it once, but that's like 10 years ago.  But I had AD Admin access, so for me it wasn't a problem...  You might ask AD admin access in an AD test container!